# Why is this Importxml formula not working?

Tags: json, xml, google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

The following formula does work for some, but not for others:

```
=IFNA(VALUE(IMPORTXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/C2PU.SI", "//*[@class=""D(ib) Mend(20px)""]/span[1]")))
```

If used without `IFNA`, it says 'Resource at url not found'.

Here's the value I'm trying to pull in:
[image]

I appreciate if you could point me to the right direction.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It does not return any values even for simple importxml.
It seems the site is generated by javascript or protected so it can't be scraped by importxml.

Comment: Hi! What's curious is that about 60% of the rows in the file do bring values, but not a couple of them, as the one shown above.
I thought it was because it was jv-based, but since some of them show up, then it got me intrigued.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the "inspect" tool as it will show the DOM as it's being rendered by the web browser including modifications to the source code by client-side JavaScript, instead look at the source code.

Resources

- [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115664/88163)

Answer (score 1):

The structure of the DOM is generated by javascript. Nevertheless, all informations you need are contained by a json string called here root.App.main. You can get all the data by these way

```
function extract(url){
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  return source.match(/(?<=root.App.main = ).*(?=}}}})/g) + '}}}}'
}
```

and then retrieve the data by conventionnal json parsing. This will give you the value

```
[![function marketPrice() {
  var code = 'C2PU.SI'
  var url='https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + code
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  var jsonString = source.match(/(?<=root.App.main = ).*(?=}}}})/g) + '}}}}'
  var data = JSON.parse(jsonString)
  var regularMarketPrice = data.context.dispatcher.stores.StreamDataStore.quoteData.item(code).regularMarketPrice.raw
  Logger.log(regularMarketPrice)
}
Object.prototype.item=function(i){return this\[i\]};][1]][1]
```

[image]